# Refactor code to make more generic method

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to try and refactor this method a bit better while I am having some difficulty in understand the async I have a web  api2 project which I use my data access layer to share to a phone app. I am not sure if I have the syntax correct I am using a xamrian shared library here in a xamrian forms app.

I will have various methods link get clients which will have the end point API/clients but obv their return type would be different.

How would one make the below work well with a list view say.

How would I consume the below method as well , what is general practise to then store the jobs locally in sql lite.

```
public string BaseUrl { get; set; }
public string EndPoint { get; set; }
```

Lets go out to the web service and grab the job list.

```
public async List<Job> GetJSON()
{
        List<Job> rootObject = new List<Job>();

        try
        {
            var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync("http://myinternaliis/api/job");
            string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
             if (json != "")
            {
                rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< List<Job>>(json);
            }

        }
        catch (InvalidCastException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        return await rootObject;

 }
```

Thanks for help in improving my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like:

```
public async Task<T> GetJson<T>(string url)
{
    using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return (T)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }
}
```

Usually I have:
`IApi` - defines all the API methods
`IHttpService` - defines methods like Get, Post and etc.
`IJsonConverter` - defines methods like serialize and deserialize.

Here is an example:

```
public interface IJsonConverter
{
    T Deserialize<T>(string json);
    string Serialize<T>(T data);
}

public class JsonConveter : IJsonConverter
{
    public T Deserialize<T>(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    public string Serialize<T>(T data) => JsonConvert.Serialize(data);
}

public interface IHttpService
{
    Task<T> Get<T>(string url);
}

public class HttpService : IHttpService
{
    readonly IJsonConverter jsonConverter;

    public HttpService(IJsonConverter jsonConverter)
    {
        this.jsonConverter = jsonConverter;
    }

    public async Task<T> Get<T>(string url)
    {
        using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return jsonConverter.Deserialize<T>(json);
        }
    }
}

public interface IApi
{
    Task<List<Job>> GetJobs();
}

public class Api : IApi
{
    readonly string url = "http://myinternaliis/api/";
    readonly IHttpService httpService;

    public Api(IHttpService httpService)
    {
        this.httpService = httpService;
    }

    public Task<List<Job>> GetJobs() => httpService.Get<List<Job>>($"{url}job");
}
```

Comment: How would i actually cosume it on the front end its rather excellent code by the way

Comment: The consumption should be done via IApi instance, for example await api.GetJobs();